# Search each line of text for specific ID#, then add to list there is a match in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for ways of searching lines of text for an ID#.  Once that ID# is found I would like that entire line of text to be added to a list.

This is what I have so far.

```
import subprocess
import re

bash = ("curl************************>> ~/Desktop/output.txt")
output = subprocess.check_output([bash], shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
with open('/******/output.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    everything = myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
    brokendownbyline = re.findall(r'{\"EGG\"(.*?)SHELL',str(everything))
for i in brokendownbyline:
print(i)
```

This code prints something like this:

```
"addjaid fja fahf ioah fa hdfh ahf 1234 asl kjas kdjf l akdjf"
"alkgad fganf daohdg o aunf g aoh oahf 9876 asl kdfna lk jfds"
"kl asdjfk ajsdfja sfiha flka jlkd jfakjfda ijf 4567 asdkf"
"asdkjfnajs dhfuioahfj a bnfgiuabf 3456asdkl fafaadhaa"
"ajsdfjaod ifjoa isdjfoia jdfoia hdgo iaf4637ads jfajis"
```

Again each line has an ID#.  I'm only looking for a certain ID#s.  Once the ID# is found I want that line or lines of text to be added a list and everything else can be ignored.

Comment: where in your code do specify the "certain ID#" that you want to search for and save?

Comment: There's nothing in the code above.  I played around with a few things and failed to get only the lines I need (which is why I omitted it above). @downshift

Comment: Is there any predictability;  Are all IDs a certain length?  Are they sprinkled next to words, i.e. no spaces?

Comment: I'm not sure of how you want to do it. What do `subprocess.check_output`, `curl***`, and `[bash]` mean. That aside, seems like a lot of overhead work, when you could just do something like, if searching for `9876`: `find_id = 9876;

found_list = [];

regex = re.compile(str(find_id));

with open('output.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    for line in myfile.readlines():
        if regex.search(line):
            found_list.append(line)`

Comment: Each line of text has multiple ID#s corresponding to different things.  But the one I am looking for is basically a GUID.  It appears in the line of text similar to this--> :"AAAA-BBB-ade98adsf897da", <--  My plan was to search by only the alphanumeric portion that comes after AAAA-BBB.  But each line contains words, spaces, commas, colons, quote marks, braces and brackets scattered about the text.  @Tony

Comment: why not just search for the the content you are looking for? the words, spaces, commas, colons, quote marks, braces and brackets scattered throughout won't affect your search, or would it, if so how? Using the phrase `if thenumber in line:` or a regex of the number to search should do the job, I think.

Comment: I'm using an API that runs in Linux terminal to acquire the raw data.  Which is what the first two lines are doing.  I'll give your suggestion a shot and see what happens.  Thanks!  @downshift

Comment: I do not believe my search would be affected by all the noise surrounding it. @downshift

Comment: Ok, sounds good, if those lines work for you to get the data, try different methods of searching for the `ID` info you're looking for and update with what doesn't work, and we'll go from there.

Comment: I just learned an important thing about curl commands.  The output of the command is one contiguous string of data.  My mistake was believing the output of the print statement at the end of my code above actually turned the contiguous string into individual lines of text.  Despite appearing that way it was in actuality still just a contiguous string of data.  And each of the solutions posted here would put everything onto a single line because the program would find the ID# I was searching for, find it and insert the entire line into the list because it wasn't actually broken up.  @downshift

Comment: Yes that's true, knowing that, are you able to make the code work now?

Comment: Thanks to everybody here and onsite help I was able to get the code working.  I appreciate it.  I'll post the solution that worked for me too. @downshift

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you're using bash to do this. You also don't explain your exact goal very well but from my interpretation, for a given ID of whatever, let's say 34, you want to find all lines that contain the ID 34 and add the entire line to a list.

This can be achieved rather easily like so:

```
import os

line_list = []

with open(os.path.join(os.environ["HOMEPATH"], "Desktop/output.txt")) as f:
    for line in f:
        if "34" in line:
            line_list.append(line)

for l in line_list:
    print(l)
```

Answer (score 0):

So the other solutions here suggested using `in` keyword, which will be quick but you can't pass a list to compare against a string.

```
["f","b"] in "foo boo" #type error
```

Instead I would use the regex to match, and then use set intersection to compare the two.

```
#update this list as needed
IDS = ["1234", "4567", "4637"]
rows = ["addjaid fja fahf ioah fa hdfh ahf 1234 asl kjas kdjf l akdjf",
        "alkgad fganf daohdg o aunf g aoh oahf 9876 asl kdfna lk jfds",
        "kl asdjfk ajsdfja sfiha flka jlkd jfakjfda ijf 4567 asdkf",
        "asdkjfnajs dhfuioahfj a bnfgiuabf 3456asdkl fafaadhaa",
        "ajsdfjaod ifjoa isdjfoia jdfoia hdgo iaf4637ads jfajis"]

for row in rows:
  if(set(IDS)&set(re.findall(r"[0-9]+", row))): #& finds intersection
    print(row)
```

Prints just the matching rows:

```
addjaid fja fahf ioah fa hdfh ahf 1234 asl kjas kdjf l akdjf
kl asdjfk ajsdfja sfiha flka jlkd jfakjfda ijf 4567 asdkf
ajsdfjaod ifjoa isdjfoia jdfoia hdgo iaf4637ads jfajis
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess
import re

listed = []
bash = ("curl************************>> ~/Desktop/output.txt")
output = subprocess.check_output([bash], shell=True, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
with open('/******/output.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    everything = myfile.read()
    brokendownbyline = re.findall(r'{\"EGG\"(.*?)SHELL',str(everything))
    for i in brokendownbyline:
        if "1234564789" in i:
            listed.append(i)
for j in listed:
    print(j)
```

This was the final solution that worked for me.